# How can I achieve this red vintage look?

Tags: post-processing, vintage, warmth, split-tone

I would like to know what kind of post processing I need to do in order to get a similar result to the below picture. And how much light is needed in order for this to work.

My 2 cents is that there's split toning involved in this. But since I'm a beginner I can't yet tell exactly what it is.

https://500px.com/photo/118141531/once-upon-a-time-by-giuseppe-mangiullo

Comment: The image is not showing

Comment: What is the "special effect" you are looking for ? What have you tried to reproduce it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, here is a downsized version of the original you are referring to:

[image]

This looks like a clear case of high black level with a reddish tint.  Let's see.

Yup, the black level is (.307, .071, .032).  Just correcting for that alone yields this:

[image]

The darkest part is now black and the lightest white.  It still looks somewhat washed out and with a reddish tint.  By adjusting black to the darkest of the left and bottom of the lens and the white balance to the reflection off the prism, we get:

[image]

All that was done here is expand the range from (.420, .118, .027) to (1.000, .819, .512) to the full black to white range.  This proves the original had elevated black level with strong red, and also overall red balance.

Comment: Very good! I will try to accomplish the same result with another picture of mine of an antique camera. By tint do you mean split toning Or real tinting of all colors? Cheers.